# paypal express sandbox not working before some days

Tags: asp.net, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I have implemented  PayPal express checkout on my site.And it's working fine on live website. But  before some days  my sandbox environment is not working , it getting error  "Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream". I thing papal upgrade  his version . Can anybody let me know what can i do change on my code for running papal sandbox .

Answer (score 1):

Paypal is working on security updates available on the sandbox but not on the production environment yet. You can check this page (if not already) : https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/

Try to see if you have a more detailed log under your Paypal account.

Comment: I checked this link but i can't understand what we need to changes  on my code ?